# Print previous occurrence of a regexp after a match is found with grep (Bash)

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk, grep

I have spent some time trying to find the answer to this question but with no luck...

I am writing a script which takes a string as input, then searches through a cvs log for a match. The output should be the filename prior to the matching string. I can write a regex to match the filename without any trouble, however I am unsure how to look back for the last occurrence of a regex after a match is made...

There are obviously many files in the cvs log that I will be parsing and the number of lines between the filename and the input string is unknown so cannot do anything like 'grep -B4' etc...

---

EXAMPLE BELOW (cvs log with irrelevant bits removed) - Need to match a string (which will be given as input to script (e.g. 120233)) and retrieve the filename associated with it, which here will be (Aliases.xml). As I said there are many files so although the regex will match many filenames, i am only interested in the one prior to my matched string.

This is my first time posting here and I am new to programming so I hope this makes sense.

```
----------


RCS file: /user1/cvs/Aliases.xml

revision 1.18
date: 2015/03/13 16:21:07; 

FIX - 217427 - fixed error....

revision 1.17
date: 2013/03/27 08:03:36; 

IMPROVEMENT - 120233 - some improvement
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you tried so far in your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` command for this:

```
cvs log | awk -F '[:, ]+' -v s='120233' '/RCS file:/{f=$3} f && $0 ~ s{print f; f=""}'
```

**Explanation:**

```
-F '[:, ]+'    # make one or more of colon, comma or <space> a field saprator
-v s='120233'  # pass search string to awk in variable s
/RCS file:/    # search for string "RCS file:"
{f=$3}         # store filename in variable f
f && $0 ~ s    # if f is NOT_EMPTY and line matches variable s
print f; f=""  # print filename from variable f and set f to EMPTY
```

Comment: That only prints one occurrence (OP did not limit the question in that respect).

Comment: A little more than that: removing the exit will print as many copies of the match as there are following non-matching lines.

Comment: @anubhava Hi, thanks for getting back to me! I did a quick check earlier and it seems to be working. Although I am slightly confused about the last part of your command -  f && $0 ~ s{print f; f=""}'   - could you provide a little clarification on what exactly is going on. Sorry, i have only been using bash for a couple of months and am pretty new to programming in general. Hope this is ok and thanks for the quick response :-)

Comment: specifically i am confused about the f && $0. I understand f is a variable containing the filename. However as far as i can see, && means continue if the return status of f is 0. This dis what i need clarification with as i don't see how f can have a return status of 0

Comment: @lwhalle: I have added explanation of awk command into my answer. I am using `f && $0 ~ s` to avoid printing same filename again for repeat match of search string `s` in the `cvs log`.

Comment: Thanks, that explanation makes perfect sense! I appreciate your help :-)